Applying to PhD programs with only 3 years of undergrad in the US
I am an undergraduate at UC Berkeley majoring in statistics. I can graduate in three years because of high school credits. I originally thought I should add another major or just take lots of extra classes in order to be in undergrad for four years. I did some statistical research relating to certain social sciences, and this really inspired me to want to continue with research, so I am now hoping to apply to statistics PhD programs once I finish undergraduate.
Is it better or worse for me to graduate in three years or four years in terms of PhD applications? It seems that I can just finish my PhD research a year earlier and spend a whole years' less on tuition. On the flip side, I may not have as much experience when applying, and although I would have completed my major, there might be other useful courses that I will potentially miss out on.
The last option -- is this viable? -- is to apply in my 3rd year, and if I don't get into any programs, apply again after a fourth year.
Might graduating in three years hurt my PhD admission chances?

If the courses you did take were the standard set for your major, and you did well in them, what is the worry?

Also related: Better chances for math grad school: graduate in three years or four?
